# Minesweeper field marking

Tags: c, interview-questions, minesweeper

I just did an interview where the last challenge was to write a function that reads a minesweeper matrix from a file and marks how many bombs there are around each cell. I had 20 min and had a `<` comparison that should have been `<=`. My main question is how I could have done it faster since it only took me 5 min to locate the bug and fix it. The other thing I would like to know is what a reviewer probably would think about it.

Here's my hacky code (the only requirement was to produce the correct output):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void read_matrix(char* dest, char const* file)
{
  FILE* input = fopen(file, "r");
  char temp[128];
  int d= 0;

  fread(temp, 1, sizeof temp, input);

  for(int i = 0; i < 128; ++i){
    if(' ' != temp[i] && '\n' != temp[i]){
      dest[d++] = temp[i];
    }
  }
  fclose(input);
}

char _grid_at(char const* grid, int x, int y)
{
  return grid[y * 8 + x];
}

int _surround_count(char const* grid, int x, int y)
{
  int count = 0;
  int x0 = x;
  int x1 = x;
  int y0 = y;
  int y1 = y;

  if(x > 0){
    x0 = x - 1;
  }
  if(x < 7){
    x1 = x + 1;
  }
  if(y > 0){
    y0 = y - 1;
  }
  if(y < 7){
    y1 = y + 1;
  }

  // here's where the problem was
  for(x = x0; x <= x1; ++x){
    for(y = y0; y <= y1; ++y){
      if('X' == _grid_at(grid, x, y)){
        count += 1;
      }
    }
  }

  return count;
} 

void mark_field(char* dest, char const* src)
{  
  for(int x = 0; x < 8; ++x){
    for(int y = 0; y < 8; ++y){
      if('X' != src[y*8+x]){      
        dest[y*8 + x] = '0' + _surround_count(src, x, y);
      }
      else {
        dest[y*8 + x] = 'X';
      }
    }
  }
}

void print_field(char const* field)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 64; ++i){
    putchar(field[i]);
    if((i & 7) == 7){
      putchar('\n');
    }
  }

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  char matrix[64];

  read_matrix(matrix, argv[1]);
  print_field(matrix);
  puts("------------");

  char count[64];
  mark_field(count, matrix);
  print_field(count);

  return 0;
}
```

**Input:**

```
X O O X X X O O
O O O O X O X X
X X O X X O O O
O X O O O X X X
O O X X X X O X
X O X X X O X O
O O O X O X O X
X O X X O X O X
```

**Output:**

```
X 1 1 X X X 3 2
3 3 3 5 X 5 X X
X X 3 X X 5 5 4
3 X 5 5 6 X X X
2 4 X X X X 6 X
X 3 X X X 5 X 3
2 4 5 X 6 X 5 X
X 2 X X 4 X 4 X
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Interview Notices

#### Check the result of system calls

```
FILE* input = fopen(file, "r");      // Can return null
fread(temp, 1, sizeof temp, input);  // returns the number read (which may not be sizeof temp
fclose(input);                       // Can fail
```

#### Style

Personally don't like:

```
' ' != temp[i] && '\n' != temp[i]
```

Reads way too much like [Yoda conditionals](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/162256/12917) (which went out of style ten years ago). Its not the natural way to expresses a test in your brain.

```
temp[i] != ' ' && temp[i] != '\n'
```

Reads much more naturally (at least to an English speaker). Though in an interview I would not knock points off for this. If I hired you I would re-train you to do it the other way though.

Is this the correct/good interface?

```
void read_matrix(char* dest, char const* file)
```

I don't like that `dest` is an array of `char`. Are you optimizing for space? Where you asked to optimize for space? I would change that to an array of `int`, as that expresses intent much more clearly.

```
void read_matrix(int* dest, char const* file)
```

I think manually checking for space is making this complex. I would have used the `scanf` library function to do that work for me.

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 128; ++i){
    if(' ' != temp[i] && '\n' != temp[i]){
       dest[d++] = temp[i];
    }
 }


// note: I would have made the `dest` array integers
for(int i = 0; i < 128; ++i){
    if (sscanf(temp, " %d", dest + i) != 1) {
        // ERROR
    }
}
```

Functions beginning with an underscore and a lowercase letter are reserved in the global scope.

```
char _grid_at(char const* grid, int x, int y)
int  _surround_count(char const* grid, int x, int y)
//   ^^^ reserved identifier.
```

Don't change the first letter to upper case as an underscore followed by an upper case letter is reserved in all contexts.

I can see why you had an issue (all those tests).

A simple optimization for this is to place your grid inside a grid that is one square larger vertically and horizontally. So if you have an 8×8 grid, place it inside a 10×10 grid. Then mark all the cells around the side as having zero in them.

Then when you call `surround_count()` you can add the cost of all the squares around the cell:

```
int surround_count(char const* grid, int x, int y)
{
     assert ( 1 <= x && x <= 8 && 1 <= y && y <= 8);

     int count = 0;
     for(int h = -1; h <= 1; ++h) {
         for(int v = -1; v <= 1; ++v) {
             count += isBombAt(grid, x + h, y + v);
         }
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I specifically asked about the return values and didn't handle to save time. I chose `char` for the `read_matrix()` because the file has either 'X' or 'O'. The underscored names is a convention I use to write `static` functions, which I didn't mark as such because of time pressure. The 9x9 without checks is a great idea. I also shouldn't have used flat arrays.

Comment: `" "` not needed in `sscanf(temp, " %d", dest + i)`.  `sscanf(temp, "%d", dest + i)` would function the same

Comment: @Douglas: That habit for global functions is one you are going to have to change. Those identifiers are reserved for use by the implementation. The [C standard:](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) See Section `7.1.3 Reserved identifiers` => `All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers
with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.`

Comment: I understand why you choose `char` I just think it is the wrong choice. As you are reading into a grid that is used to count numbers. So by using `int` rather than `char` you are imparting information to the next programmer about the intent of the grid. Unless this is a Minesweeper solver for an embedded device were memory is exceedingly limited and you want to squeeze out every byte).

Comment: @LokiAstari I don't use leading underscores for global functions, only for variables and functions which are only visible in the same file, isn't that exactly what they are reserved for?

Comment: @Douglas Incorrect. If they are in file scope identifiers with a leading underscore are reserved for the implementation. That means they are not available for use by the developer.

Comment: @LokiAstari What would a reserved identifier with file scope be and where would it come from? Does it mean any header supplied by the implementation might define variables and functions with file scope for every file that includes it? Or something more strange like the compiler can decide to define that name for any reason?

Comment: @Douglas reserved means that the implementation (the compiler and associated tools) may use that identifier for anything it likes. So even if your code works as expected with this implementation it may fail in the next version of the compilation tools as the compiler now uses that identifier for something internal.